# How make drop down selected in blade template in Laravel 4.1?

Tags: php, laravel-4, template-engine, laravel-blade

I am trying to show a drop down of all countries. In edit page I want to make a country as selected . say `India` as `selected=selected`.

```
<div class="large-3 columns">
    {{ Form::label('country') }}
</div>
<div class="large-4 columns">
    @include("common.country")
</div>
```

How can I make it. Is it possible to pass the value in array in `@include("common.country")` ?

Comment: Could you post the content of your included view?

Comment: @DamienPirsy: `@section("country")

    @if (count($countries) > 0)
        {{ Form::select('country', $countries, null, array('id' => 'country')); }}
    @endif
        
@show`

Answer (score 6):

```
echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S');
```

Here Small is default selected. We can add the default selected item at end.
[Drop-Down Lists](http://laravel.com/docs/html#drop-down-lists)

Comment: Actually saying, `@include("common.country")` is generating select tag in the view.

Comment: {{ Form::select('country', $countries, null, array('id' => 'country')); }}  Here the first argument country is the name and the second one is the array of country list. Third argument is the default value which is selected . But here its null.

Comment: I agree Praveen, but in the view page form tag is not used. just `@include("common.country")` is used and it will display drop down list of all countries.

Comment: You can add this on your included view

Answer (score 3):

It's as easy as writing the name of the country you want as default after the "variable" that posts the countries, as a 'Blade' argument.

```
{{ Form::select('country', $countries, 'Palestine', ['id' => 'countrySelector', 'class' => 'formElement']) }}
```